# unique key warning even after generating hash from string

Tags: reactjs

I have tried multiple ways and I have run out of ideas. I am not able to get rid of the warning "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop". I am displaying error messages of form validation.

```
<Alert variant="danger" id="shopFormErrorsAlert" className={hasError?"visible":"invisible"}>
  {Object.keys(shopFormErrors).map((objKey, index) => {                            
    return (
      <ul id={objKey}>
      {shopFormErrors[objKey]['error'] && Object.keys(shopFormErrors[objKey]['errorMsg']).map((hash) => {
        return (
          <li id={hash}>{shopFormErrors[objKey]['errorMsg'][hash]}</li>
        )
      })}
      </ul>                            
    )
  })}                            
</Alert>
```

I introduced the hash (which is created based on the content) as array key to overcome the warning

```
  nObj[fieldName]['errorMsg'] = []
  var id
  var i; // creating a unique id to over come unique 'key' warning 
  for (i = 0; i<errors[fieldName].length ; i++){
    id = 'i' + hashCode(errors[fieldName][i]); 
    nObj[fieldName]['errorMsg'][id] = errors[fieldName][i]
  }

  nObj[fieldName]['error'] = true
  nObj[fieldName]['className'] = 'inputRequired'
```

The generated html

```
<div role="alert" id="shopFormErrorsAlert" class="fade visible alert alert-danger show">
    <ul id="pincode">
        <li id="i-1650524308">The pincode field is required.</li>
        <li id="i-557689933">The pincode must be a number.</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="email">
        <li id="i16726618">The email must be a valid email address.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to provide the generated hash to the key attribute in the list something like this `<li key={hash}>{shopFormErrors[objKey]['errorMsg'][hash]}</li>`

Comment: btw, why was id not assumed as a key. Isn't react suppose to auto recognize it ?

Comment: No it wont auto recognise, refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) and [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a key for each and every element in your `map()`. In this case add `key` prop to `ul`:

```
<ul id={hash} key={index}>
  <li key={`${index}_li`}>...</li>
</ul>
```

Note that here I have added `index` but you can use any unique key(your `hash` is better if it is unique).

[From doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html):

> React will mutate every child instead of realizing it can keep the
>   `<li>Duke</li>` and `<li>Villanova</li>` subtrees intact. This
>   inefficiency can be a problem.
>
> [Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)
>
> In order to solve this issue, React supports a key attribute. When
>   children have keys, React uses the key to match children in the
>   original tree with children in the subsequent tree. For example,
>   adding a key to our inefficient example above can make the tree
>   conversion efficient:
>
> ```
> <ul>
>   <li key="2015">Duke</li>
>   <li key="2016">Villanova</li>
> </ul>
>
> <ul>
>   <li key="2014">Connecticut</li>
>   <li key="2015">Duke</li>
>   <li key="2016">Villanova</li>
> </ul>
> ```

Comment: @Vikram you need to add attribute to `<li>` too.

Comment: add a key property to the `<li>` like I added to `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

So each element react create should have a unique key which can be anything , but that should be unique.

```
<Alert variant="danger" id="shopFormErrorsAlert" className={hasError?"visible":"invisible"}>
  {Object.keys(shopFormErrors).map((objKey, index) => {                            
    return (
      <ul id={objKey}>
      {shopFormErrors[objKey]['error'] && Object.keys(shopFormErrors[objKey]['errorMsg']).map((hash) => {
        return (
          <li id={hash}> key={hash} {shopFormErrors[objKey]['errorMsg'][hash]}</li>
        )
      })}
      </ul>                            
    )
  })}                            
</Alert>
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. this works. I did not know I should explicitly mention "key" even if there was 
 a "id"